# CKAN spatial basemap subdomain placeholder not respected

Tags: ckan

Trying to switch our CKAN instance away from MapQuest and have tried to use:

```
ckanext.spatial.common_map.type = custom
ckanext.spatial.common_map.custom.url = http://{s}.osm.maptiles.xyz/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

However the subdomain placeholder `{s}` isn't being substituted.  The maps are requesting tiles from `%7Bs%7D.osm.maptiles.xyz/...`
(where `%7Bs%7D` is `{s}` URL encoded)

Our instance is served over HTTPS and I was wondering if SSL could be the issue?  We have managed to get it working by replacing `{s}` with the explicit subdomain `a` though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if `ckanext.spatial.common_map.type = custom`, no default subdomains are passed to L.TileLayer unless they are explicitly set.

Try:

```
ckanext.spatial.common_map.subdomains = abc
```